# Migration from Skydrive to Onedrive

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, onedrive

Once I've updated my App, I got a 'warning' message from Certification test:

> The app and its associated metadata does not accurately represent its functionality, capabilities, and features.
>
> NOTE: Please update any references to SkyDrive within your app or metadata to "OneDrive (formerly SkyDrive)" by May 31.

But as I've checked I'm already using [Live SDK 5.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40739) and I cannot see `Branding.OneDrive`.

As I've also checked [Core API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521.aspx) hadn't changed much (for now).

Does anybody know something about this? Or simply I need a little more patience when new SDK is released?

(I hope it's not too much off-topic)

Comment: Do you have any hardcoded string with `Skydrive`?

Comment: do you have a menu option, button text etc that mentions SkyDrive? (I ask because my WP app does) - if so see if changing that fixes it.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek @KateGregory There are probably some. I'll change them and see if that helps (with nearest update or beta). In near future new SDK will probably be released with new Branding (I wonder how much time I will have to change it). I wonder also if core API and its reference to `https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive?access_token` (and so on) will also change somehow - [sice it's the same for now with onedrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/jj680723.aspx). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live SDK 5.6 is out now, but none of the code or API references have been removed. This ensures backwards compatibility with existing code written for previous versions of Live SDK. This includes the API paths, which will continue to include the term skydrive.

The store approval process is flagging UI references to Skydrive. If you have strings that are visible to the user that reference Skydrive you should replace them with references to OneDrive and resubmit your app.